# Cannot assign <User: username> must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a web gallery in Django, but I'm stuck right at the beginning. I can't assign the user ID as a foreign key in the database.

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from .forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, ImageForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import ImageForm

@login_required
def add_image_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.save(commit=False)
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = get_user_model().objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                print(user_obj) #I receive the expected value.[marek]
                print(user_obj.id) #I receive the expected value.[2]
                print(user_obj.username) #I receive the expected value.[marek]
                image.username = user_obj
                image.save()
                return redirect('user_panel')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_image.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py files

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'użytkownik'
        verbose_name_plural = 'użytkownicy'
        ordering = ['username']
        permissions = [('special_permission', 'Specjalne uprawnienie')]

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        related_name='main_users',  # zmianiona nazwa odwrotnego dostępu
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='groups',
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
        related_query_name='main_user'
    )

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        related_name='main_users',  
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        related_query_name='main_user'
    )


class Image(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    is_for_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Image


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='Nazwa użytkownika',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True})
    )
    password = forms.CharField(label='Hasło', widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    price = forms.DecimalField()
    for_sale = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'for_sale', 'image']
```

I'am getting ValueError at /add_image/
Cannot assign "<User: marek>": "Image.username" must be a "User" instance.

I tried to assign request.user to user_obj, but then I received the following error: ValueError at /add_image/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: marek>>": "Image.username" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Have you altered the `AUTH_USERNAME_MODEL` setting to point to the new user model?